# `DateTime.strptime` returns invalid date for weekday/time string

Tags: ruby, date, strptime

Why won't Ruby's `strptime` convert this to a DateTime object:

```
DateTime.strptime('Monday 10:20:20', '%A %H:%M:%S')
# => ArgumentError: invalid date
```

While these work?

```
DateTime.strptime('Wednesday', '%A')
# => #<DateTime: 2015-11-18T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457345j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.strptime('10:20:20', '%H:%M:%S')
# => #<DateTime: 2015-11-18T10:20:20+00:00 ((2457345j,37220s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: I believe because there is an uncertainty in what this should result to, next Monday, or previous one.

Comment: @mudasobwa I originally thought that, but the example of the last two working is interesting - they're both even more ambiguous, yet DateTime doesn't have any problems.

Comment: Excellent question that needs to be asked of the development team; It sounds like a bug to me. In the future, it'd make a stronger question if you use `'Monday'` for both the initial example and the second `DateTime.strptime('Wednesday', '%A')` as initially it wasn't clear if `strptime` was choking on `"Monday"` vs. `"Wednesday"` or a change in format.

Comment: `DateTime.strptime('Monday 10:20', '%A %H:%M')` works, too. How odd!

Comment: `Date._strptime('Monday 10:20:20', '%A %H:%M:%S')` also works properly; it looks like `date_core.c`’s `rt_complete_frags` is at fault, though it’s really hard to read.

Comment: Posted a workaround that takes advantage of the `_strptime` method @minitech mentioned, but this definitely seems like a bug. Please link to it here if/when you report it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug - [minitech's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785322/datetime-strptime-returns-invalid-date-for-weekday-time-string#comment55342916_33785322) is spot on. For now, though, a workaround (because you probably want this to work *now*):

You can split it on the space, get the date from the weekday, then get the time component from the other string (using the [`_strptime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/_strptime/class) method minitech mentioned).  Then you can set the time on the first date to the time component from the second string:

```
def datetime_from_weekday_time_string(string)
  components = string.split(" ")
  date = DateTime.strptime(components[0], '%A')
  time = Date._strptime(components[1], '%H:%M:%S') # returns a hash like {:hour=>10, :min=>20, :sec=>20} 
  return date.change(time)
end

2.2.2 :021 > datetime_from_weekday_time_string("Monday 10:20:20")
 => Mon, 16 Nov 2015 10:20:20 +0000 

2.2.2 :022 > datetime_from_weekday_time_string("Saturday 11:45:21")
 => Sat, 21 Nov 2015 11:45:21 +0000

2.2.2 :023 > datetime_from_weekday_time_string("Thursday 23:59:59")
 => Thu, 19 Nov 2015 23:59:59 +0000
```